# Hyperref causing "red" to appear before section numbers in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, color, packages

I am working with a LaTeX template and am noticing a big difference between the compiled document after adding \usepackage{hyperref} at the top. Before adding it, the Table of Contents section is exactly how I want it, with nothing weird going on before each line:
[image]

But after adding \usepackage{hyperref}, the string "red" appears before the section number of each entry in the Table of Contents:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening or how I can fix it?

Edit: here's a MWE.

```
\documentclass{MyUniversityThesisTemplate.cls} 

%(article class doesn't work, doc wouldn't even have table of contents)

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{Section 1}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\section{What do we want to measure?}

\section{Variables}

\section{Actors}

\section{Causal Relationships}

\section{Interdependencies}

\end{document}
```

And here's a MWE for the class document (might not be working though):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\ProvidesClass{MyUniversityThesisTemplate}[2011/02/16 v1.4.2 My University Thesis class]

\RequirePackage{setspace}

%here I skip some code

\DeclareOption{myorder}{

  \renewcommand*{\begincmd}{\doublespacing}}

\DeclareOption{lot}{\renewcommand*{\makelot}{

  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}\listoftables}}

\DeclareOption{lof}{\renewcommand*{\makelof}{

  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}\listoffigures}}

\DeclareOption{los}{

  \renewcommand*{\makelos}{

    \RequirePackage{losymbol}

    \section*{List of Symbols\@mkboth {LIST OF SYMBOLS}{LIST OF SYMBOLS}}

    \@starttoc{los}

    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Symbols}

  }

}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}

\ProcessOptions

%here I skip some code

\AtBeginDocument{\begincmd}

\endinput
```

Comment: you should make sure that `hyperref` is the very last package you load, so put it at the bottom of your preamble, just before `\begin{document}`. Have you tested that?

Comment: @T.Pluess, yeah, it is currently the very last package that I load. Thanks for the idea though

Comment: Untested but I doubt very much that the stripped down class actually triggers your problem - there is nowhere something looking like "red" and hyperref doesn't invent such a word. You will have to show a real minimal example that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The `article` class does not have `\chapter`s, so this cannot work. But `report` and `book` have. And if I use one of those and add `\tableofcontents` to your MWE, then I even get a table of contents and everything is fine.

Comment: There isn't enough information to reproduce your problem, but random guess: Does `\tableofcontents` end up inside of `\AtBeginDocument` by any chance?

Comment: @DavidPurton, thank you for this guess. The only instances of \tableofcontents and \AtBeginDocument (in order) in the class document are: \makeacknowledgements\tableofcontents\clearpage and \AtBeginDocument{\begincmd}

Comment: Does this still confirm what you suspected?

Comment: Possibly. You need to expand your MWE above to show how `\tableofcontents` is set up and called. It must end up *after* `\begin{document}`, so if it appears directly in your class then this is wrong. If it's in your class as a hook that somehow runs between `\usepackage{hyperref}` and the first code after `\begin{document}` you will get an error about an undefined control sequence and the word *red* in your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THE PROBLEM HAS BEEN SOLVED BY INSERTING

\RequirePackage{hyperref}

AFTER THE

\RequirePackage{setspace}

LINE OF CODE IN THE CLASS FILE!!!!!!!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=,
filecolor=magenta,
urlcolor=cyan,
}

It worked for me. (notice "linkcolor=")