# Displaying PDF bookmarks with the document class of Preprint JHEP

Tags: table-of-contents, bookmarks

I like to add PDF bookmarks in a document that is built with the class `JHEP.cls 3.1.5` (The class is now [DEPRECATED](https://jhep.sissa.it/jhep/help/JHEP/TeXclass/tools_JHEPlog.html)).

I am trying with the option `bookmarsnumbered` of the package `hyperref`:

```
\usepackage{hyperref} 
    \hypersetup{ 
        bookmarksnumbered,
        colorlinks=true, 
        linkcolor={}, 
        filecolor={},
        urlcolor={}, 
        }
```

Here, I kept the linkcolor and urlclor blank because it was causing a different issue ([Hyperref causing "red" to appear before section numbers in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/493891/114006)).

Though it seems to generate my desired output with bookmarks, it's giving the following error  `Undefined control sequence`:

```
<recently read> \Hy@colorlink 
                              
l.1 ...e {1}The Relativistic String}{2}{section.1}
                                                  %
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\close@pdflink ->\Hy@endcolorlink 
                                  \Hy@VerboseLinkStop \pdfendlink 
l.1 ...e {1}The Relativistic String}{2}{section.1}
                                                  %
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I am not sure yet which specific part in the class file is causing the issue, so I am sharing the full `package.cls` via the [Overleaf project](https://www.overleaf.com/read/qtgnkcqrrwgb) that has the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,hyper,letterpaper]{package}         % For preprint
\usepackage{hyperref} 
    \hypersetup{ 
        bookmarksnumbered,
        colorlinks=true, 
        linkcolor={}, 
        filecolor={},
        urlcolor={}, 
        }
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}
\font\mybb=msbm10 at 10pt
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{epsfig}


\title{{\Huge String Theory}}
\author{}
\preprint{}

\abstract{}

\begin{document}

\newpage
\section{The Relativistic String}
\label{classical}

All lecture courses on string theory start with a discussion of the point particle. Ours is no exception. We'll take a flying tour through the physics of the relativistic point particle and extract a couple of important lessons that we'll take with us as we move on to string theory.

\end{document}
```

What would be the effective way to generate PDF bookmarks for this document class in a way that avoids these errors?

Comment: please do not use external links but that class loads  pdfcolor.tex for a simple older than latex2e color and does simple linking macros directly with pdfliteral not using hyperref. I would not consider using hyperref, use the class' own link macros or better use a class written this century that is compatible with hyperref.